# MultiLine Form in HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms, multiline

I'm trying to get some input from a user and use that input in a php script.  Right now I have a form tag, from the little I understand, this cannot have multiline input.  The solution seems to be a TextArea, however I'm not sure how to get the input from a TextArea.

Here's my code with the form :

```
<form action="traitement_cmd.php" method="post" >
    Enter Cmd: <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="100" name="cmd"/>
</form>
```

The textarea tag doesn't seem to have the same attributes as a form tag, so I'm not sure how I should change my code.  I also need a button for the user to click to send his input to the php script.

How can I change my code to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the textarea inside the form, and the submit button too:

```html
<form action="traitement_cmd.php" method="post" >
     Enter Cmd: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" name="cmd"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: a-ha
thank you, I thought i was suposed to change the for by a textarea, silly me !

Answer (score 3):

Straight from the source, the [HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7):

> This example creates a TEXTAREA control that is 20 rows by 80 columns and contains two lines of text initially. The TEXTAREA is followed by submit and reset buttons.
>
> ```
> <FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/text-read" method="post">
>    <P>
>    <TEXTAREA name="thetext" rows="20" cols="80">
>    First line of initial text.
>    Second line of initial text.
>    </TEXTAREA>
>    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"><INPUT type="reset">
>    </P>
> </FORM>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

textarea attributes are "rows" and "cols".